# Как разделить строку на подстроки в PL/SQL блоке?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть строка:

```
обл. Иваново, г. Иваново, ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1
```

Как сделать так чтобы на выходе получить в столбик:

```
обл. Иваново, г. Иваново,

ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1
```

Через регулярку получается разделить по символу, но не получается по слову через запятую. Перенос строки через `select char(10)` тоже не даёт результатов. А мне нужно сделать как показано выше, т.е после второй запятой сделать перенос на новую строку.

Comment: Вот именно так, одну запись поделить строго на две? формулируйте тогда точное правило разделения.

Answer (score 2):

Если надо быстро и грязно то

```
WITH DATA AS
      ( SELECT 'обл. Иваново, г. Иваново, ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1' str FROM dual
      )
    SELECT trim(COLUMN_VALUE) str
      FROM DATA, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(str, 'ул.', '", "ул.') || '"'))  ;
```

по второй запятой:

```
WITH DATA AS
      ( SELECT 'обл. Иваново, г. Иваново, ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1' str FROM dual
      )
    SELECT trim(COLUMN_VALUE) str
      FROM DATA, xmltable(('"' || REGEXP_REPLACE(str, ',', '", ",',1 ,2) || '"' ))  ;
```

Comment: dSH ,а если красиво допустим нужно ,то как ?!

Comment: Запилив все это в функцию ?

Comment: @Саша Функция возвращает один результат. А вы в вопросе хотели 2 строки, т.е. 2 результата

Comment: Mike хорошо тогда как это сделать красиво ? Как это в идеале должно выглядеть ? Как по правильному!

Comment: в функцию которая возвращает табличный тип запихните. Потому что так править легче потом - потому что с адресами много мороки. По-правильному все части адреса изначально должны отдельно лежать в полях таблиц.

Comment: dSH , спс будем работать, а то как и всегда все такие умные ,а обьяснить никто не может толком)! Спасибо дружище

Comment: dSH так в том и дело ,что в базе изначально сделали до меня через одно место )!

Answer (score 2):

> после второй запятой сделать перенос на новую строку

Очень просто, одна строка кода в PL/SQL блоке:

```sql
var res varchar2
declare 
    str varchar2 (128) := 'обл. Иваново, г. Иваново, ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1';
    fromPos number := 1; occur number := 2;
begin 
    :res := regexp_replace (str, '(,\s*)', '\1'||chr (10), fromPos, occur);
end;
/
print res
```

Результат:

```
RES
---------------------------
обл. Иваново, г. Иваново, 
ул. Иваново д.1 кв.1
```

Answer (score 0):

В 2 шага

1. получить массив, например по регулярке см. функцию string_to_array
2. преобразобвать массив в столбец поможет функция unnest

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html подробнее тут

Comment: Вопрос касался Oracle. там нет массивов и соответствующих функций

Answer (score 0):

Используя регулярные выражения:

```
WITH 
  TMain AS (SELECT '100,200,300,400,500' || ',' AS str
              FROM DUAL)
SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  FROM TMain
  CONNECT BY NVL(regexp_instr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level), 0) <> 0;
```

[здесь можно посмотреть](https://habr.com/ru/post/418271/)

Comment: Видел это пример ,но он все делает в столбик через запятую .Вот как сделать так ,чтобы он выводил все после второй запятой ?! Мозгов у меня хватмло

Comment: Таких примеров кстати тьма , но вот ,что нужно было мне не было . Мне уже показали выше пример как нужно действовать)! Спасибо

Comment: в Вашем задание как раз речь о столбике идет, я и показал как делать в столбик)